# How can I change the order in which the Document ID column appears in the form?

Tags: feature, document, library, ordering

I want to re-order where the Document ID field appears when you view the 
properties of a document. How is it possible to do this?

It's not possible to simply do column ordering with the Document ID field as it is not a normal column. It is switched on by enabling the Document ID feature.